# How to set rest of variables in vector to zero without defining each of them individually

Tags: r, vector

I have a list of 80 stocks. The weights of the rest of the stocks equal zero. I only want the weight for 3 of the stocks. I don't want to write them out on the vector every time.

EIRL

TLT

BND

... 80 stocks

TSLA

```
StockW <- c(EIRL=5/10,TLT=2/10,BND=3/10, #[the rest of the variables=0])
```

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset and show expected output for it so that it is easier to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Create a logical vector with `%in%` on the `names` of the 'StockW' with the preferred elements, negate (`!`) so that TRUE -> FALSE and FALSE -> TRUE, use that index to subset the 'StockW' and assign (`<-`) them to 0

```
StockW[!names(StockW) %in% c("EIRL", "TLT", "BND")] <- 0
```